# select all rows that have more than one ID in a specific date

Tags: sql-server

My table:

```
Items   | Price  |  UpdateAt
  1     |  2000  | 02/02/2015
  2     |  4000  | 06/04/2015
  3     |  2150  | 07/05/2015
  4     |  1800  | 07/05/2015
  5     |  5540  | 08/16/2015
  4     |  1700  | 12/24/2015
  5     |  5200  | 12/26/2015
  2     |  3900  | 01/01/2016
  4     |  2000  | 06/14/2016
```

As you can see, this is a table that keeps items' price as well as their old price before the last update.

Now I need to find the rows which :

- UpdateAt is more than 1 year ago from now
- Must have updated price at least once ever since
- Aren't the most up-to-date price

So with those conditions, the result from the above table should be :

```
Items   | Price  |  UpdateAt
  2     |  4000  | 06/04/2015
  4     |  1800  | 07/05/2015
```

I can achieve what I need with this

```
Declare @LastUpdate date set @LastUpdate = DATEADD(YEAER, -1, GETDATE())
select Items, UpdateAt from ITEM_PRICE where Items in (
    select Items from (
       select Items, count(Items) as C from ITEM_PRICE group by Items) T
    where T.C > 1) 
and UpdateAt < @LastUpdate
```

But since I am still a newbie in sqlserver, and this need to be done in vb.net, passing along that query with lots of select in it seems sloppy and hard to maintain.

So, I would like to ask if anyone can give me a simpler solution ?

Sorry, i edited my question as I need one more condition to be met after trying @Tim Biegeleisen's answer, which is indeed the correct one for the question before edit. And I can't figure this out anymore.

Why I need all those condition, it's because I'm having to clean up the table: Clearing off the data that's older than 1 year, while still keeping the most up-to-date item price.

Comment: Item 2 is updated only once,how it is your expected result 
?

Comment: Item 3 was never updated in the recent year, at least not in the sample data you showed us.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Item 2 is updated once at 06/04/2015 which is more than 1 year from now, and it updated again at  01/01/2016 so the row with 06/04/2015 should appear in the result.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen yes, item 3 should not appear. My mistake. I will edit my question prior to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer below, I use a subquery to identify all items which appear in the table during the last year.  This is the requirement of having an updated price "at least once ever since."  In the outer query, I restrict to only records which are *older* than one year from now, which is the other part of the requirement.  An `INNER JOIN` is used, because we want to filter off records which do not meet both criteria.

```
SELECT t1.Items, t1.Price, t1.UpdateAt
FROM ITEM_PRICE t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Items
    FROM ITEM_PRICE
    WHERE UpdateAt > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
) t2
    ON t1.Items = t2.Items
WHERE t1.UpdateAt <= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Once again, SQL Fiddle is having problems simulating SQL Server.  But I went ahead and created a Fiddle in MySQL, which looks nearly identical to my SQL Server answer.  You can verify that the logic and output are correct.

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I'm sorry i can't reply sooner. Yes, your answer is correctly get the result I desired, and it beats mine as well. I tried your answer, and it leads me to one more condition.. to filter out the one that most up-to-date price, as i edited my question. While i'm trying to figure it out, i hope you can take some more of your time to help me..

Comment: I don't follow what your new requirement is because there is no sample data showing it, or the sample output didn't change.  You might want to post a new question rather than changing this one multiple times.

Comment: I did as you suggest and added one clearer question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367323/cleaning-up-old-record-to-a-specific-date-how-to-select-the-old-record](here). I hope you can share me some idea there either.