# Cleaning up old record to a specific date: How to select the old record?

Tags: sql-server

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346750/select-all-rows-that-have-more-than-one-id-in-a-specific-date/38346833?noredirect=1#comment64117717_38346833), which I now need to perform. I edited it a few times to match the current requirement, and now I think i will make it clearer as a final solution for me as well.

My table:

```
Items   | Price  |  UpdateAt
  1     |  2000  | 02/02/2015
  2     |  4000  | 06/04/2015
  1     |  2500  | 05/25/2015
  3     |  2150  | 07/05/2015
  4     |  1800  | 07/05/2015
  5     |  5540  | 08/16/2015
  4     |  1700  | 12/24/2015
  5     |  5200  | 12/26/2015
  2     |  3900  | 01/01/2016
  4     |  2000  | 06/14/2016
```

As you can see, this is a table that keeps items' price as well as their old price before the last update.

Now I need to find the rows which :

- UpdateAt is more than 1 year ago from now
- Must have updated price at least once ever since
- Aren't the most up-to-date price

Why those conditions? Because I need to perform a cleanup on that table off of those records that older than 1 year, while still maintain the full item list.

So with those conditions, the result from the above table should be :

```
Items   | Price  |  UpdateAt
  1     |  2000  | 02/02/2015
  2     |  4000  | 06/04/2015
  4     |  1800  | 07/05/2015
```

The update at 02/02/2015 of item 1 should be selected, while the update no. 2 at 05/25/2015, though still over 1 year old, should not because it is the most up-to-date price for item 1.
Item 3 isn't in the list because it never been updated, hence its price remain the same until now so i don't need to clean it up.

At first i think it wouldn't be so hard, and i think I've already had an answer but as I proceed, it isn't something that easy anymore.

@Tim Biegeleisen provided me with an answer in the last question, but it doesn't select the items which price doesn't change over the year at all, which i'm having to deal with now.

I need a solution to effectively clean up the table - it isn't necessary to follow 3 conditions above if it can produce the same result as I need : Records that needs to be deleted.

Comment: You should show sample data which contains the use case where the "price doesn't change over the year at all."

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in this sample case, your query doesn't return any of the item 1's row ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
DECLARE @Prices TABLE(Items   INT, Price  DECIMAL(10,2),  UpdateAt DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Prices
VALUES
       (1, 2000, '02/02/2015')
      ,(2, 4000, '06/04/2015')
      ,(1, 2500, '05/25/2015')
      ,(3, 2150, '07/05/2015')
      ,(4, 1800, '07/05/2015')
      ,(5, 5540, '08/16/2015')
      ,(4, 1700, '12/24/2015')
      ,(5, 5200, '12/26/2015')
      ,(2, 3900, '01/01/2016')
      ,(4, 2000, '06/14/2016')


SELECT p.Items, p.Price, p.UpdateAt
FROM @Prices p
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                p1.Items,
                p1.UpdateAt,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p1.Items ORDER BY p1.UpdateAt DESC) AS RowNo
            FROM @Prices p1     
            ) AS hp ON hp.Items = p.Items
                AND hp.UpdateAt = p.UpdateAt
WHERE hp.RowNo > 1  -- spare one price for each item at any date
    AND p.UpdateAt < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())   -- remove only prices older than a year
```

the result is:

```
Items       Price                                   UpdateAt                
----------- --------------------------------------- ----------------------- 
1           2000.00                                 2015-02-02 00:00:00.000 
2           4000.00                                 2015-06-04 00:00:00.000 
4           1800.00                                 2015-07-05 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thank you for your query, it seems it is doing what i'm looking for. While it produce the desired result, the answer below also return the same, but without the LEFT JOIN part.
I will have to do some safe-check first for both of the query on my table before accepting an answer.

Comment: to delete records, you need LEFT JOIN method or else you have to use CTE to generate RowNo beforehand and then delete from the CTE.

Comment: yes, thank you for pointing that out for me. I appreciate it. I will accept your answer. It is indeed what i need for this matter.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return the dataset you're looking for:

```
SELECT t1.Items, t1.Price, t1.UpdateAt
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        t2.Items, 
        t2.Price, 
        t2.UpdateAt, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.Items ORDER BY t2.UpdateAt DESC) AS rn
    FROM [Table] AS t2
) AS t1
WHERE t1.rn > 1
AND t1.UpdateAt < DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: this is the same answer as @Jatin Patel, but without the LEFT JOIN part. Though it seems to produce the same result, I still need to check, just to be safe upon delete.

Comment: Yes, it is. Infact I upvoted the @Jatin Patel one. He answered while I was writing my post.